# What is the best approach to implement an RTC build for WebSphere

Tags: ant, websphere, rtc, jazz

I would like to utilize the RTC (v2.x) build for Java EE projects created in RAD (v8) and deploy them on WebSphere (v7).

Independently of RTC build i am able to create all sorts of ant scripts and jython scripts to perform automated tasks. The problem is to integrate this into a single RTC build.

The path I'm on now is:
- RTC build definition calls external build command which is a ms-dos .bat file that call's the Rational Build Utility headless ant with an ant build script.
- The ant build script uses 1)projectImport 2)workspaceBuild and 3)exec to call wsadmin with a jython deploy script.

Right now the build fails because the workspaceBuild task fails because we've defined a target runtime that does not exist in the headlles ant workspace. If someone knows how to add/define a new target runtime into a headless ant workspace that would be very helpfull.

I can't help feeling that i'm on the wrong track and feel quit stuck between the different environments and I'm wondering how other people implement their RTC build for a WebSphere target.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [DeveloperWorks article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/10/enhancecontinuousintegrationwiththerationalapplicationdeveloperbuildutility/) that explains how to use the RAD Ant tasks in a continuous build scenario.  For the target runtime, you would define that in Eclipse, export your preferences, then import them during the build using the workspacePreferenceFile Ant task with useEclipsePrefs="true".  The article uses Hudson, but the same approach should work for RTC Build.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the developerworks article. I missed that one.  I can now import the preferences but the build still fails because of a missing library to the REST facet. That one is not in the workspace preferences.